# Wordpress how can we get the featured image or other attached media from post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the featured image of my custom post type. I also have attachments in my custom post however I am not able to see the data. Am I using the wrong query method? In my json output I see general information however it is missing information such as feature image link.

```
add_filter("wcra_pictures_callback", "wcra_pictures_callback_handler");

function wcra_pictures_callback_handler($param) {
  //$param = All GET/POST values will be received from endpoint
  
    // WP QUERY
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => $param['post_type'],
        'author' => $param['user_id'],
        'author_name' => $param['author'],
        'orderby' => $param['orderby'],
        'order'   => $param['order'],
        'posts_per_page' => $param['posts_per_page'],
    ]);

    // // Get Posts
    // $posts = get_posts([
    //     'post_type' => $param['post_type'],
    //     'author' => $param['user_id'],
    //     'author_name' => $param['author'],
    //     'orderby' => $param['orderby'],
    //     'order'   => $param['order'],
    //     'posts_per_page' => $param['posts_per_page'],
    // ]);
  
  return $query;
}
```

current out does not include data showing any attachments or links or feature image. How can I get that information.

```
{
   "status": "OK",
   "response": "Response OK",
   "code": 200,
   "data": {
       "query": {
           "post_type": "picture",
           "author": null,
           "author_name": null,
           "orderby": null,
           "order": null,
           "posts_per_page": null
       },
       "query_vars": {
           "post_type": "picture",
           "author": "",
           "author_name": "",
           "orderby": null,
           "order": "DESC",
           "posts_per_page": 10,
           "error": "",
           "m": "",
           "p": 0,
           "post_parent": "",
           "subpost": "",
           "subpost_id": "",
           "attachment": "",
           "attachment_id": 0,
           "name": "",
           "pagename": "",
           "page_id": 0,
           "second": "",
           "minute": "",
           "hour": "",
           "day": 0,
           "monthnum": 0,
           "year": 0,
           "w": 0,
           "category_name": "",
           "tag": "",
           "cat": "",
           "tag_id": "",
           "feed": "",
           "tb": "",
           "paged": 0,
           "meta_key": "",
           "meta_value": "",
           "preview": "",
           "s": "",
           "sentence": "",
           "title": "",
           "fields": "",
           "menu_order": "",
           "embed": "",
           "category__in": [],
           "category__not_in": [],
           "category__and": [],
           "post__in": [],
           "post__not_in": [],
           "post_name__in": [],
           "tag__in": [],
           "tag__not_in": [],
           "tag__and": [],
           "tag_slug__in": [],
           "tag_slug__and": [],
           "post_parent__in": [],
           "post_parent__not_in": [],
           "author__in": [],
           "author__not_in": [],
           "ignore_sticky_posts": false,
           "suppress_filters": false,
           "cache_results": true,
           "update_post_term_cache": true,
           "lazy_load_term_meta": true,
           "update_post_meta_cache": true,
           "nopaging": false,
           "comments_per_page": "50",
           "no_found_rows": false
       },
       "tax_query": {
           "queries": [],
           "relation": "AND",
           "queried_terms": [],
           "primary_table": "SQTSXGdhposts",
           "primary_id_column": "ID"
       },
       "meta_query": {
           "queries": [],
           "relation": null,
           "meta_table": null,
           "meta_id_column": null,
           "primary_table": null,
           "primary_id_column": null
       },
       "date_query": false,
       "request": "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT SQTSXGdhposts.ID FROM SQTSXGdhposts  LEFT JOIN SQTSXGdhpostmeta AS myarmjoin ON (SQTSXGdhposts.ID = myarmjoin.post_id AND myarmjoin.meta_key = 'arm_access_plan' )  WHERE 1=1  AND ((SQTSXGdhposts.post_type = 'picture' AND (SQTSXGdhposts.post_status = 'publish' OR SQTSXGdhposts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'))) AND ( myarmjoin.post_id IS NULL )  ORDER BY SQTSXGdhposts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10",
       "posts": [
           {
               "ID": 254,
               "post_author": "2",
               "post_date": "2022-02-07 16:53:39",
               "post_date_gmt": "2022-02-07 16:53:39",
               "post_content": "",
               "post_title": "Aurora_BG_7",
               "post_excerpt": "",
               "post_status": "publish",
               "comment_status": "open",
               "ping_status": "closed",
               "post_password": "",
               "post_name": "aurora_bg_7",
               "to_ping": "",
               "pinged": "",
               "post_modified": "2022-02-07 16:53:39",
               "post_modified_gmt": "2022-02-07 16:53:39",
               "post_content_filtered": "",
               "post_parent": 0,
               "guid": "https://cloud.elmc.app/picture/aurora_bg_7",
               "menu_order": 0,
               "post_type": "picture",
               "post_mime_type": "",
               "comment_count": "0",
               "filter": "raw"
           },
           {
               "ID": 249,
               "post_author": "2",
               "post_date": "2022-02-07 16:46:58",
               "post_date_gmt": "2022-02-07 16:46:58",
               "post_content": "",
               "post_title": "134909",
               "post_excerpt": "",
               "post_status": "publish",
               "comment_status": "open",
               "ping_status": "closed",
               "post_password": "",
               "post_name": "134909",
               "to_ping": "",
               "pinged": "",
               "post_modified": "2022-02-07 16:46:58",
               "post_modified_gmt": "2022-02-07 16:46:58",
               "post_content_filtered": "",
               "post_parent": 0,
               "guid": "https://cloud.elmc.app/picture/134909",
               "menu_order": 0,
               "post_type": "picture",
               "post_mime_type": "",
               "comment_count": "0",
               "filter": "raw"
           },
           {
               "ID": 147,
               "post_author": "1",
               "post_date": "2022-02-06 21:36:28",
               "post_date_gmt": "2022-02-06 21:36:28",
               "post_content": "",
               "post_title": "Scene 4 On",
               "post_excerpt": "",
               "post_status": "publish",
               "comment_status": "open",
               "ping_status": "closed",
               "post_password": "",
               "post_name": "scene-4-on",
               "to_ping": "",
               "pinged": "",
               "post_modified": "2022-02-06 21:36:28",
               "post_modified_gmt": "2022-02-06 21:36:28",
               "post_content_filtered": "",
               "post_parent": 0,
               "guid": "https://cloud.elmc.app/picture/scene-4-on",
               "menu_order": 0,
               "post_type": "picture",
               "post_mime_type": "",
               "comment_count": "0",
               "filter": "raw"
           },
           {
               "ID": 142,
               "post_author": "2",
               "post_date": "2022-02-06 03:49:57",
               "post_date_gmt": "2022-02-06 03:49:57",
               "post_content": "",
               "post_title": "No_video",
               "post_excerpt": "",
               "post_status": "publish",
               "comment_status": "open",
               "ping_status": "closed",
               "post_password": "",
               "post_name": "no_video",
               "to_ping": "",
               "pinged": "",
               "post_modified": "2022-02-06 03:49:57",
               "post_modified_gmt": "2022-02-06 03:49:57",
               "post_content_filtered": "",
               "post_parent": 0,
               "guid": "https://cloud.elmc.app/picture/no_video",
               "menu_order": 0,
               "post_type": "picture",
               "post_mime_type": "",
               "comment_count": "0",
               "filter": "raw"
           }
       ],
       "post_count": 4,
       "current_post": -1,
       "in_the_loop": false,
       "post": {
           "ID": 254,
           "post_author": "2",
           "post_date": "2022-02-07 16:53:39",
           "post_date_gmt": "2022-02-07 16:53:39",
           "post_content": "",
           "post_title": "Aurora_BG_7",
           "post_excerpt": "",
           "post_status": "publish",
           "comment_status": "open",
           "ping_status": "closed",
           "post_password": "",
           "post_name": "aurora_bg_7",
           "to_ping": "",
           "pinged": "",
           "post_modified": "2022-02-07 16:53:39",
           "post_modified_gmt": "2022-02-07 16:53:39",
           "post_content_filtered": "",
           "post_parent": 0,
           "guid": "https://cloud.elmc.app/picture/aurora_bg_7",
           "menu_order": 0,
           "post_type": "picture",
           "post_mime_type": "",
           "comment_count": "0",
           "filter": "raw"
       },
       "comment_count": 0,
       "current_comment": -1,
       "found_posts": 4,
       "max_num_pages": 1,
       "max_num_comment_pages": 0,
       "is_single": false,
       "is_preview": false,
       "is_page": false,
       "is_archive": true,
       "is_date": false,
       "is_year": false,
       "is_month": false,
       "is_day": false,
       "is_time": false,
       "is_author": false,
       "is_category": false,
       "is_tag": false,
       "is_tax": false,
       "is_search": false,
       "is_feed": false,
       "is_comment_feed": false,
       "is_trackback": false,
       "is_home": false,
       "is_privacy_policy": false,
       "is_404": false,
       "is_embed": false,
       "is_paged": false,
       "is_admin": false,
       "is_attachment": false,
       "is_singular": false,
       "is_robots": false,
       "is_favicon": false,
       "is_posts_page": false,
       "is_post_type_archive": true,
       "thumbnails_cached": false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `the_post_thumbnail` to output a featured image of a post while inside a while loop where you are changing the current post (by calling `$query->the_post()`)

Outside of a 'WordPress' loop you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail` which accepts a post id as the first parameter.

### Examples

*Please note, in the two first examples the functions return the image within an  tag, not the url of the image.*

This would be suited to your situation as you have an instance of `WP_Query` to loop through.

```php
$query = new WP_Query($args);

while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();
    the_post_thumbnail('full', ['class' => 'my image classes']); // 'full' is original uploaded size I believe.
    
    // Need image as a variable?
    // $image = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'full', ['class' => 'my image class'];
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // reset usage of 'the_post()'
```

Alternative: iterate using `foreach` on the array of posts.

```php
$query = new WP_Query($args);

$posts = $query->posts; // now an array of posts
foreach($posts as $post){
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full', ['class' => 'my image classes'];
}
```

### Obtaining image URL string only

```php
// Inside 'WordPress' loop
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');

// Inside foreach loop
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full);
```

#### Documentation references

- [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)
- [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)
- [the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)
- [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)
- [Explanation of 'the_post' functionality](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)